# Trying to edit the breadcrumbs or title for taxonomies in views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to show breadcrumbs and taxonomies title in browser tab with Drupal 6, but not getting the result, I'm having issues generating a custom breadcrumb.

I put a php code in views>header like:-

```
global $base_url;
$path = $base_url."/topics/".arg(1)."/".arg(2);

$title = ucfirst(str_replace("-"," ",arg(2)));
drupal_set_title($title);
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l($title, $path);

drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
print views_embed_view('article_tag_name', 'default', array(arg(2)));
```

But this code showing a term id at breadcrumbs and browser tab. How would I go about adding a breadcrumb and title to a view?